# Can't get id of related model/

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get the id of a `patient` in the `reports` controller. Each `user` has `patients`, while each `patient` can have `reports` created by the doctor.

I am getting this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ReportsController#new
>   Couldn't find Patient with 'id'=
>   Extracted source (around line #49):

Patient Show Page, link to new report:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <% if @patient.id == current_user.id %>
    <%= link_to "Add Visit Report", new_report_path(@patient),class: "button_one" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Reports Controller:

```
def new
  @report = Report.new 
end

private

def report_params
  params.require(:report).permit(:date, :report)
end

def find_patient
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])  //Line 49 where error is
end

def find_report
  @report = Report.find(params[:id])
end
```

User, Patient and Report models:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  validates :name, presence:true
  validates :age, presence:true
  validates :phone, presence:true
  validates :ailment, presence:true
  validates :apointment, presence:true
  validates :status, presence:true

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy

  def to_s
    name
  end
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :patient
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Clearance::User

  has_many :patients
  has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Routes:

```
       reports GET    /reports(.:format)                      reports#index
               POST   /reports(.:format)                      reports#create
    new_report GET    /reports/new(.:format)                  reports#new
   edit_report GET    /reports/:id/edit(.:format)             reports#edit
        report GET    /reports/:id(.:format)                  reports#show
               PATCH  /reports/:id(.:format)                  reports#update
               PUT    /reports/:id(.:format)                  reports#update
               DELETE /reports/:id(.:format)                  reports#destroy
```

Comment: Could you post the result of `rails routes` (relating to `reports`) in your question please?

Comment: how are you calling this `find_patient` method?

Comment: That's Done @SRack

Comment: Cheers @Jayk. Does muZk's answer _definitely_ not work? It really looks to me like it should.

Comment: Actually - there's a typo in their answer which would explain it if you've copy and pasted. Try `new_report_path(patient_id: @patient.id)`

Comment: Agreed with @SRack, i have also edited MuZk's answer

Comment: Great works now. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your link to this one:

```
<%= link_to "Add Visit Report", new_report_path(patient_id: @patient.id),class: "button_one" %>
```

This will pass a param `patient_id` to the `new_report_path` which is used in your controller: `@patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])`

Comment: Nope same error. I have update the question to point which line error is on

Comment: Typo in there: `parient_id:` v `patient_id:` :)